# Spivak's "Calculus" Chapter 9 Problem 7 about definition of functions

Tags: calculus, functions, definition

In a problem Spivak mentions that $f'(x^2)$ means the derivative of $f$ at the number which we happen to be calling $x^2$; it is not the derivative at $x$ of the function $g(x) = f(x^2)$.

This sentence really struck me because it means that I have been doing all of the Spivak's previous problems in a wrong way.

For example, when doing the problem: prove that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0} f(x^2)$, I used the following: $f(x^2) = (g \circ h) (x)$, where $g(x) = f(x)$ and $h(x) = x^2$.

Why am I so shocked: I always used this notation and I was always able to prove everything I needed - I have never found a contradiction.

So, how to think about $f(x^2)$ ? And if it really just means that it is the value of the function evaluated at some number $x^2$ then why write it like a square at all (I assume that probably to say that the numbers considered are positive) and how to interpret $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x^2)$?

Comment: You have not been doing the problems wrong, based on the example you showed.  It's true and correct that $f(x^2) = (g \circ h)(x)$, where $g(x) = f(x)$ and $h(x) = x^2$.  Why would Spivak's statement about $f'(x^2)$ imply that this isn't true?  [And based on your previous correct understanding, why would you think that $f'(x^2)$ is the derivative at $x$ of the function $g(x) = f(x^2)$?]

Comment: But the function $f$ is defined as : $f(x) := x^3$. So its derivative is defined: $f'$ must be $3x^2$.

Comment: Thus, the "tricky" exercise ask to compute (evaluate) $f'$ (that is a known function) at different "points" : $9, 3^2,a^2,x^2$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Do I understand correctly that if $g(x) = f'(x)$ and $h(x) = x^2$ then $f'(x^2) = (g \circ h)(x)$ and that's it?

Comment: Both you and Spivak are correct. The notation $f'(x)$ where $x$ is a variable means $\dfrac{d} {dx} f(x) $ and hence $f'(g(x)) $ means $(f'\circ g) (x)$. It does not mean $(f\circ g) '(x) $.

Comment: I do not really understand why you doubt yourself or Spivak. The notation is not as confusing as you might think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f'(x^2)$ is indeed not the same as $(f \circ h)'(x)$. Its maybe easier to be confused if you use $\frac{d}{dx}$ notation, and write $f(x)$ with $x$ 'indeterminate' to mean the function $f = f(x)$, giving (in general) the non-identity
$$ \frac{df}{dx}(x^2) \neq \frac{d}{dx} (f(x^2))$$

In the case of the limit $\lim_{x→ 0} f(x^2)$ there is no issue because there is no way to ambiguously bracket the expression.